# how to make a child div should not inherit opacity from parent div?

Tags: css

Hi all i created a parent div `.ima` inside which one div called `.txt` When i give a opacity to `.ima` then the opacity is applied to `.txt` automatically this is obvious. But i don't want it to be in this way.

Only `.ima` should be in 0.5 Opacity and the Text in `.txt` should be 100% visible.

Is there a way to do this?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f4Vzj/1/)

I tried Giving Opacity to 1 in `.txt` its not working. I might Be doing this in a wrong way I don't know.Any help?

**Here i mention the Different From the Question refering for possible Duplicate**

There They Have given Suggestion to Use **rgba** But here i don't want to use it Because if i use `rgba` then this will become either black or some other color that we'll mention.

I want to use background image here.

This is a sample am proposed.

Things like there is no possible.

Also I don't want to use .png images(with semi-transparency). images are subject to change that is why.

Any Way thanks for guys Who have given their answers here.

Comment: make the child a sibling of the parent?

Comment: Try using `>` selector.

Comment: You cannot do this, opacity is inherited. You can, however, use RGBA color or semitransparent image for the parent.

Comment: I am using BG image so if i give RGBA, color will occur.i would like to do it with image.@MightyPork

Comment: Raj, Check the link adrift has provided.

Comment: @Adrift Here am having Background Image this is different from the question you are pointing.from that question if i use RGBA image will go only color i can make. I want this along with Image, SO i thought this would be resourceful

Comment: I am targeting to Use Background Image instead of RGBA

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way of doing this assumes you only want `.ima`'s background to be transparent, in which case you should remove `opacity` and establish a `background-colour` with a value of `rgba(X%,X%,X%, .5)`, in which case `.txt` inherits nothing and you can carry on.

```
<div class="ima">
    <div class="txt">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS for transparent background:

```
.ima {
    /* rgba is Red, Green, Blue, Alpha:
     * put in your colour as RGB then add opacity at the end */
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

But if you want some of `.ima`'s children nodes to inherit the transparency (for instance text and  elements other than `.txt`) then the simplest way is to create an immediate descendant that matches the dimensions of `.ima` and applies the `opacity` rule:

```
<div class="ima">
    <div class="txt">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="ima__transparency">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ima {
    position: relative;
}

.ima__transparency {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: .5;
}

.txt {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[Example with background image](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/33Geu/).

Comment: Thanks, i want to use background image not colour

Comment: @raj Edited the answer to be a bit more explicit as to how you achieve that.

Comment: Thanks, I would like to have BG image alone transparent other than that i don't want any child to be transparent, i tried Selectors Like `.ima .txt{values}` but no effect

Comment: @raj If you want the background image to be transparent you will need to apply the transparency to an extra element inside `.ima`: use the second scenario (the first one I wrote) and add the background image to `.ima__transparency`.

Comment: @raj I updated my answer with an example and an extra rule which stops the background appearing on top of your content.

Comment: So it is not possible to make it with css alone without changing markup, Right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34841/discussion-between-raj-and-barney)

Answer (score 2):

You can't not inherit opacity, your options are:

- Adjust your markup so that `.txt` is not a child of `.ima` and then use absolute positioning
- Don't use opacity, make `.txt` cover the same area as `.ima` and give `.txt` a semi-transparent background
- If your target audience supports [gradients](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients) and [multiple backgrounds](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds), [you can layer an obscuring gradient over the image](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/f4Vzj/5/):

  ```
  background: linear-gradient( rgba(255,255,255,0.5),rgba(255,255,255,0.5)),
              url('http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/NewportOR_ROW5865752464_1366x768.jpg');
  ```

Using this approach you actually only need [one `div`](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/f4Vzj/6/) if it's just the text and the image you want to display.

Comment: +1, nice solution! Even better than the gradient would be a [solid color image](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/CR-css3-images-20120417/#color-images), but they seem to be less supported than gradients :-(

Answer (score 0):

Create a png image(1px/1px) transparent with 60% opacity using photoshop and call in your parent div i.e.

```
.ima{
  background:url(imagename.png) repeat 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't using opacity as it is inherited by design.

You could, however, if you are only seeking to make the background color of the parent div semi-transparent using rgba color syntax and a fallback for older versions of ie that do not support the syntax.

e.g. Create a white background with an opacity of 50%.

```
.parent{
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7FFFFFFF,endColorstr=#7FFFFFFF)"; /* IE8 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#7FFFFFFF,endColorstr=#7FFFFFFF);   /* IE6 & 7 */
    zoom: 1;
}

/* IE9 hack to remove filter */
.parent:not(dummy) {
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false)";
}
```

The first two hex values in the filters represent the opacity of the background. There is a great explanation and rgba to hex converter [here](http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/).

**Word of note**. Using this technique reveals a bug in IE where hyperlinks will be exposed through the background of the container if placed above them, for example if used to generate a model background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :after/:before

HTML 
`<div>asdsadasd</div>`
CSS

```
div{position:relative;} 
div:after{
content:''; 
position:absolute; 
top:0; 
left:0; 
width: 100%; 
height: 100%; 
background: #000; 
opacity:0.3; 
z-index: -1;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, the opacity property applies on the whole block. It means that if you apply a 1 opacity to any child element, it will have the maximum opacity towards its parent.

I suggest you use a semi transparent PNG background and add a fix so that older versions of internet explorer handle the opacity :

```
.ima {
   width:auto;
   filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(enabled=true, sizingMethod=crop, src='url_to_transparent_image.png');
}

.ima[class] {
   background-image:url('url_to_transparent_image.png');
}

.txt {
   color:white;
}
```

That is, it's only if you really need a totally opaque text. You can also set the opacity of the parent a bit higher so that your text isn't too transparent and avoid using "dirty" CSS tricks.